# ext.kotlin_version = <'latest version'> error on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to place advertising in my flutter app, this is proving to be almost more complicated for me than creating the app itself (I am a newbie dev starting with flutter).

I get an error when I try to launch my app that says the following: [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dev\adtest\android\build.gradle: ext.kotlin_version = '' Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The problem seems simple, I have to update the field suggested by the console. My surprise is that the field ext.kotlin_version = " ", does not exist in my build.grade file on android/build.gradle. Neither does the buildscript { } apatagate exist that should contain it. I have android Studio installed, Flutter updated, I work with visual studio code, everything is apparently correct, except for this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stuck with the same issue, happend after i've added facebook auth plugin and updated teh app..

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70919344/11675817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same error and resolved it by this method. I hope this will also for you. Just follow these steps

- open your terminal
- run -> dart pub outdated (it will show you all outdated versions of the project)
- run -> dart pub upgrade --major-versions
- restart your android studio

Answer (score 18):

Add `ext.kotlin_version` and kotlin dependency in `<app>/android/build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0' //use latest
    ...
}

dependencies { 
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's an old question but still valid. I spent almost full day in troubleshooting and using various combinations. Ultimately I made this change in `"myapp_root_folder\android\settings.gradle"` file

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    //id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false **//Replaced this**
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false **// With This**
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This fixed also on my side the issue. 
This change is required due to to migration from flutter 3.16 to flutter 3.19. 
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Hopefully all the others will find it quicker then us :-)

Answer (score 7):

[Official Website link for getting latest version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)
you can see  <project_name>/android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

[image: You can find here]

Answer (score 3):

visit this site to get the latest version of the kotlin gradle:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

Then, go to <project_name>/android/build.gradle and **NOT** <project_name>/android/app/build.gradle

buildscript {

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21' //use latest version
```

}

Answer (score 3):

[Kotlin releases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html)
Here you can find latest kotlin version. Just copy and paste version to your **android/build.gradle**

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste.
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
On location:
android/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution works perfectly. The info in the answer is to be posted in build.gradle. With time this might be updated, just find the latest Kotlin version.

Answer (score 0):

Update kotlin version to '1.4.32'.

Copy and paste
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'` On Project-level build.gradle(/build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open your project on android studio and go to **Tools->kotlin->"Configure kotlin plugin updates"**, update and ensure you apply changes.

Step 2: navigate to your flutter project_folderName/android/build.grade file and change

buildscript {

ext.kotlin_version = 'the version you updated to'

}

step 3: build and debug your project.

Answer (score -3):

Update kotlin version to 1.9.20
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'

Comment: in new flutter project, there is no ext.kotlin_version.
Instead follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895109/323365