# Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've just updated my flutter project packages to be null-safety compliant and now Android Studio wants me to update my project to use the latest version of Kotling Gradle Plugin. Can't see where to change this though. I have tried to change `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` into `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"` but this has no effect.

My `build.grade`-file looks like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "*********"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build output:

```
BUILD FAILED in 8s
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update project/android/build.gradle:
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You need to change the kotlin version in your android root project, `projectName/android/build.gradle`, instead of `projectName/android/app/build.gradle`.

Change the version at `ext.kotlin_version` line:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // Change here
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The above solution will also works if your android part of the project is using java where the dependencies are using kotlin and you've encountered the following error:

```
Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/36814238b86d8b6b6f9e4e1263bce879/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: 
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. 
The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
```

AndroidStudio or IntelliJ Idea will give hint in the project `build.gradle` file if the kotlin is not the same with the installed kotlin in the IDE.

Note:
to see the new versions of Kotlin check this link :
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

Comment: It works, but how can I identify the  kotlin_version  based on sdk

Comment: I also changed the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper to 7.3.3-all.zip

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: afaik, AndroidStudio or IntelliJ Idea will give warning if the kotlin in `build.grade` is not the same with the installed kotlin in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks man. I've been on this issue for 2 days after upgrading my dart and flutter versions

Comment: Thanks man. I've been on this issue for 2 days after upgrading my dart and flutter versions

Comment: To update grade : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69053055

Comment: To find out the latest version of Kotlin Gradle visit https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

Comment: But I am using java in flutter and not kotlin, then why I am getting this error?

Comment: @Chetan: Some of your dependencies are using kotlin, that's why you got the error.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: >Tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotling Plugin Update

Comment: now there are newer versions: check here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

Comment: why I'm I getting this error "Unresolved reference: kotlin_version"

Answer (score 28):

Update your Kotlin to the Latest version. You can see the latest version here

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' //
```

You can see the latest version of Kotlin from the below link
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions

[image]

Answer (score 13):

change build gradle to this :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

and gradle-wrapper to this :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 12):

I Update Flutter to 2.10.1
and I found All My Project Has Same Error
in app /build.gradl
you change to ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In Flutter Got to Andriod/gradle/build.gradle File 
and Updaet

Answer (score 12):

You have to change the `kotlin version` in your `android` root,  go to

```
projectName/android/build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

And change the gradle wrapper version to 6.7.1-all or higher in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

**Also you can get the lattest version** [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html)

Answer (score 9):

1. Open file : Your Project/android/settings.gradle
2. Update the line:

   id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false

   with the most recent version of kotlin
3. flutter clean then flutter run or invalidate cache

//Update the last line with the lates version of kotlin

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I don't use kotlin in my flutter project, but some of my dependencies use it (It was `assets_audio_player` for me), so I had to go to `build.gradle` for that dependency and update the kotlin version as other answers here:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

**Note 1:** you can open `build.gradle` for the library you want by opening the android module in Android Studio then go to `Gradle Scripts` from  Project tab.

[image]

**Note 2:** you can know which library is causing the error by looking at:

```
Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin'.
```

It could be more than one library, so after you change kotlin version the error will be changed.

Comment: how to solve it I updated to latest version but still getting the error

Comment: @RajaEhtisham Can you write the error line as in note 2 in my answer?

Comment: God Bless you, you saved my day, it helped me to solve this problem

Comment: I just commented `ext.kotlin_version = <>` in the libraries gradle, and automatically it will use the one I set in my app's gradle.

Answer (score 7):

change kotlin version to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'` inside `android/build.gradle` , it fixes your problem.

check all versions here [Find Latest Kotlin Version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

Comment: I created a new Flutter 3.10 project. It had the Kotlin version as `1.7.10`. So that's what I went with.

Comment: i did not work for me. i edited this line to use the latest version, still same error

Answer (score 6):

**Change ext.kotlin_version on projectName/android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22' //latest version
   repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}
```

You can get the "latest kotlin_version" using the below link
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#apply-the-plugin

Answer (score 5):

1- First change `ext.kotlin_version` on `projectName/android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
}
```

2- Second change build gradle to this :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

- Change the build gradle version to **4.1.0** or higher in the project-level `build.gradle` file:

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
  ```
- Change the gradle wrapper version to **6.7-all** or higher in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
  ```
- Change the `ext.kotlin_version` to **1.6.10** or higher in the project level `build.gradle` file:

  ```
  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // Change like this
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

After spending so many hours I have found the exact version of gradle for this issue.

1. Clear gradle cache from home directory `<YOUR HOME DIRECTORY>/.gradle/caches`
2. Delete folder in your project `<YOUR PROJECT DIRECTORY>/android/.gradle`
3. Set latest version of gradle in `android/build.gradle`. At this moment its 1.9.10. So my build.gradle file looks like
   [image]
4. Update `gradle-wrapper.properties` with below distribtutionUrl `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`
5. `flutter clean`
6. `flutter pub get`
7. Build/Run your project now.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
In Flutter Project Navigate to Android/gradle/build.gradle File
and Update Kotline Version to New Version

Answer (score 1):

> This is latest version Works for me.

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21' 
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anyone else is stumbling across an issue I had after upgrading flutter:
If you use flutter together with aws_amplify you have to also upgrade amplify. This is a issue I had with the same error message.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31640322)

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the latest version [from here.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

Answer (score 0):

A huge solution for updating the Android application is to delete the android folder and then run this:

```bash
flutter create .
```

**Note**: you can also run `flutter upgrade` command to upgrade flutter first.

Comment: this need only first project. Otherwise, so many configuration issue across with us

Answer (score 0):

This method in latest versions works

Directory

- android/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' // Put this number
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
     }
   }
```

FAQ
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/kotlin-version

Answer (score 0):

It is always worth checking that you are trying to build the right Flutter project.  I ran into this issue recently only to discover that I had accidentally switched to an older version of the project - another folder - which I had replicated when I made a long delayed `flutter pubgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my experience as a **Windows** user.

I had this error, when trying to build with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory 'D:\Users\mikyll\flutter_application\build\app\outputs\apk\release'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - D:\Users\mikyll\flutter_application\build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
    - D:\Users\mikyll\flutter_application\build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
    - D:\Users\mikyll\flutter_application\build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-x86_64-release.apk

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 56s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          117,7s

┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                                                                          │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update D:\Users\mikyll\flutter_application\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                                                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I updated `ext.kotlin_version` to the latest (1.9.22 when I'm writing this answer), but it kept failing.

As the error is suggesting, the problem was the OpenJDK Platform binary process was frozen for some reason and `flutter build` could not replace the previous built APKs with the new one, since they were busy (open in that process).

#### Solution

I solved by **terminating OpenJDK Platform binary** process from task manager, deleting the old APK releases, and the next build went straight forward

Answer (score -2):

Just restart the IDE. Worked for me.

I was using `VS Code`.