# -Flutter - The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)

Tags: flutter, arp, nt

## how can i fix the error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

```
  > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
    dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
    is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
    Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
    AAR metadata file: /home/arrakeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

```
  > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
    dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
    is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
    Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
    AAR metadata file: /home/arrakeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve the error "The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata" in native Java or Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034879/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067455/12413404 and still the error persists ?

Comment: I'm developing Flutter with Visual Studio Code. I could not find this section. I'm installing the all SDK.

Comment: The path you are looking is `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: i got new error                                                                                                                                    
   [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update /home/arrakeen/Desktop/Bilicisoft.Asti.Mobil/android/build.gradle:                    
 ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70919344/12413404 all the answers are a google search away :)

Comment: yes, I'm calling from google :D I just wanted to point it out to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to `3`1 in your ***build.gradle***(app) file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```

The ***build.gradle*** (app) is in the */app/build.gradle* of the project.