# Your project requires a newer version of Kotlin gradle plugin [flutter]

Tags: flutter, gradle

So I'm trying to build the apk for my application using the command `flutter build apk` but the below error occurs every single time:

[image]

As of now, the latest kotlin version is 1.9.0, so I did update the version to that in my `build.gradle` but the error seems to be persisting.

Here is my root level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70919127/10157127) answer your question?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I've already tried updating the kotlin_version, the error persists.

Comment: you can  try `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'` with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`

Comment: Can you upload your whole code of both build.grade file to your question and whole console logs

Answer (score -1):

1. Change kotlin version to latest one which is available at this path android/build.gradle

   ext.kotlin_version = version <-- latest version
2. Upgrade class path to latest one

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
3. Change url of android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to latest like this

   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

after following this steps you are able to solve this issue.