# problem with generating flutter apk files

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem is that when I want to create apk files (by flutter build apk  --split-per-abi ) I have the error :

[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update
D:\Programming_*Project*_\owlegram-flutter-android-1\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

and
build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com/"}
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Which version of kotlin and gradel do you offer?

Comment: Update your kotlin version from provided link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919127/your-project-requires-a-newer-version-of-the-kotlin-gradle-plugin-android-stud)

Answer (score 0):

Update kotlin version and rebuild again

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
```

Note: don't forget to run these command in terminal

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: kindly, do no answer duplicate questions.

Comment: Ok, I will try next time. 
Thank you....