Flutter Build Fails with Kotlin Version Incompatibility
I am working on a Flutter project and I'm facing an issue related to Kotlin versions. When I try to build my project, I get the following error messages indicating a version mismatch between Kotlin modules:
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/431ce31617111116ed092b20fb775fda/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/431ce31617111116ed092b20fb775fda/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/431ce31617111116ed092b20fb775fda/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6327b6d5cbee3dd5c434505ea5de9c0a/transformed/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-22.0.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/648640f83817e7438e3934ba83addfe2/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-22.0.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/digit/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c321e7444a5c731da2398570d6ef04f1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
t

Additionally, I receive this message indicating the need for a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin:
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update C:\Users\digit\Documents\flutter projects\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

My Current Setup
Here are the relevant parts of my android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle files:
android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0' // Updated to the latest version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2' // Updated Gradle Plugin
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.muhasebepro.muhasebe_pro_finall"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.muhasebepro.muhasebe_pro_finall"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


Steps I Have Tried
Updated Kotlin version to 1.9.0 in android/build.gradle.
Ensured that all dependencies use the same Kotlin version.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project using flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Request
How can I resolve this version mismatch issue and ensure that all modules use the same compatible version of Kotlin?
What I Tried and Expected
I am working on a Flutter project and encountered issues related to Kotlin versions during the build process. Here's what I have tried so far:
Updated Kotlin Version: I updated the Kotlin version to 1.9.0 in my android/build.gradle file as suggested by the error message.
Synchronized Dependencies: I ensured that all dependencies in my build.gradle files are using the same version of Kotlin.
Cleaned and Rebuilt the Project: I used flutter clean and flutter pub get to clean and fetch the dependencies again, hoping to resolve any conflicts.
Checked for Duplicate Dependencies: I verified that there are no duplicate dependencies that might be causing the conflict.

Does this answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231382/5197712

Try the above answer

You can try to force all packages to use the same kotlin version.
Just add the following to your app/build.gradle, just before apply plugin and just after dependencies.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1' }
}


It didn't work and it gives the same error again

I've passed 2 days investigating all possible solutions and suggestions, converted Gradle imperative to DSL, removed references to Kotlin stdlib. But the only one thing helped me to resolve this problem is to use latest available Kotlin and Gradle versions 2.0.20 and 8.6.0 accordingly:
id "com.android.application" version "8.6.0" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false

and also updated gradle-wrapper.properties specifying 8.7 version:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip

Hope this helps!
